# undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationController, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper, bcrypt-ruby

I'm trying to integrate oAuth2.0 In my rails-api only application, using doorkeeper. But I keep getting this error, "undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationController" and yet could not find a clear solution  on how to solve it. bellow is my application_controller.rb class, Which has the helper_method. I'm following tutorial on the link below, Any help will be appreciated.

> https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-doorkeeper-and-oauth-2-0/

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

private 

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    helper_method :current_user

end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While Andy Gauge's answer is correct; the fix is incorrect. If you want to include the Helpers module while still keeping your applications as "rails-api" then simply include the module

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Helpers
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Because APIs don't have a view, the `helper_method` method has been removed.  If you want to add your `current_user` method to a view, use ActionController::Base instead.

[ActionController included Modules on Github.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/541a51ecf8ee04f956b7d8efb13935640aa831ce/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L112) You can see here that AbstractController::Helpers is not included in the Modules collection.

In Rails 4, which the article is based, the method was included in ActionController::Helpers.  As seen in the [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method).

Workaround:

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```